# US media coverage of Dec. 2017 Israeli attack on Syria

Tags: israel, syria, media

Why is there no coverage of Dec. 2017 Israeli attack on Syria by the US media (except for UPI, VoA, RFERL, Newburgh Gazette and GKMen), according to Google News 11AM MDT, Dec. 2, 2017:

[Google News](https://news.google.com/news/story/d6iS4AgC3b7o9KM3tgqmvvJGuwVZM?ned=ca&gl=CA&hl=en-CA)

Comment: Why are you assuming US government has anything to do with what US media does and doesn't cover - especially under current administration that most media strongly opposes

Comment: I'm vtc as unclear. The second link is CNN. It seems basis of your question is not correct.

Comment: Israel has a very strong ties with the US. I doubt they would show anything that makes Israel look like aggressors. Don't even get me started on the illegal actions of NATO on Syria.

Comment: @Noah - there's an answer below that directly proves your theory wrong.

Comment: @JamesK CNN wasn't there when I saved the page (I still have it). That's why I posted the list.

Comment: @user4012 I didn't say anything about the US govt.

Comment: @KeithMcClary - you posted in Politics.SE. The whole site is about **governments**.

Comment: @user4012 "Questions related the political impact the media has (may it be an independent media outlet, or the mainstream media), or the general consensus the media has on a political topic. ..." There are other governments besides the US.

Comment: @KeithMcClary - what's the political impact of whether US media covers non-US strike in Syria?

Comment: I did not say the "US government has anything to do with it". There is more to politics than the doings of the US government. Obviously how the media covers (or ignores) foreign events has an impact on politics. Do I need to spell that out in the Question?

Comment: My original question was about the media and search engine rankings, not Israel/Syria. I may add more examples and background, eg.[Google to 'derank' Russia Today and Sputnik](http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-42065644), [Should government 'outsource' censorship to Facebook and Twitter](http://thehill.com/blogs/pundits-blog/the-administration/339339-should-government-outsource-censorship-to-facebook-and).

Comment: Downvoted because the premise is false: there is US media coverage of that event which can be found in Google News.  I saw a mention there yesterday (12/02/17), and search today returns links to Fox, CNN, Breitbart, and others.  Why the OP couldn't find it is a question better asked of Google's programmers and/or UI designers.  The absolute amount of coverage in US media probably reflects the degree to which the event is a) not really news; and b) not of much interest to most Americans.

Comment: @jamesqf As I pointed out a few comments up, the page is not static. I posted the contents of the page at that time, but someone edited it out (as you can see from the edit history). Also, someone added tags so I appear to be discrediting a "specific political cause, group or politician" which my question did not do. I think I will just delete it rather than deal with this sort of stuff.

Comment: @Keith McClary: I'm not referring to the Google News page, but to using search.  Of course the page is non-static, but that makes it rather unreasonable to complain about what happens to show up at any particular time.  (I'd sure like a way to edit out all references to Kardashians and their ilk, computer games, and so on.)  But it remains a fact that I saw articles at the approximate time you couldn't see any. sp the question seems to be more about underlying algorithms and interfaces.

Answer (score 10):

1. Because you shouldn't trust Google News as "full picture of all news". It's a black box with unknown algorithms (or alternately, you searched it the wrong way. I haven't used it in 3-4 years or more so no idea how good is its coverage nor algos).

   Let's look at two of the biggest news source on US cable/web: CNN and Fox News

   - http://www.cnn.com/world

     The ***very first*** story in the "Latest stories" section is... surprise... "Israel strikes military site near Damascus, Syria's state-run news claims".
   - http://www.foxnews.com/world.html

     The story is 11 hours old there so it's no longer top of the latest list, but: "WORLD  11 hrs ago - Syrian state media: Israeli missiles strike near Damascus"

   ## So, the question's assertion that there was no US media coverage is patently false.

---

2. Because US Media has tons of stories to cover, and many of them are far more important to news consumers, at least according to media's judgement.

   - Main stories overall on CNN, Fox, and couple of others are all domestic big stories: Trump's tax cut plan passing the Senate; and Flynn-related stuff.
   - Main stories on world sections are North Korea. For obvious reason (Hwasong-15 is ICBM designed to hit USA).

---

3. Lastly, because US Government doesn't care much (I would speculate that they tacitly approve, but don't have any evidence) - so they didn't make any moves to highlight this news, like issuing statements / press conferences.

   Again, this is about focus. Trump admin's focus is zeroed in on milking tax bill as a success story. Trump opponents' focus is zeroed in on Flynn story. Neither camp has any benefit from diluting their focuses at the moment with second-rate news that doesn't affect US domestic power balance in a meaningful way (or US geopolitical position, unlike DPRK's ICBM).

Comment: My original question (before it was messed around with and misrepresented) was about why the major search engine, which many people rely on, seems to return unbalanced results. I pointed out that the results you see may be different at different times and posted the results at that time (which was edited out). I did not say "that there was no US media coverage" , as you shout. I did not say anything about the US govt. You say you don't know anything about Google News. Fine, but I was hoping to hear from someone who did. I don't understand the upvotes since you do not answer the Q at all.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Google News aren't in scope for this site. The upvotes are because this is the only meaningful answer you can get - it explains why you saw what you saw.

Comment: OK, my next question was going to be about political (Congress & CIA) pressures on Google, FB & Twit to censor, but I won't bother.